# How to recursively travel a long list of text to search for next word that matches?

Tags: php, recursion

Here is a list of words:

```
what
do
you
fear
if
I 
ask
you
a
tricky
question
```

How can I recursively travel through this list and return every word that matches the next one?

E.g.

input:

```
$findWordFlow->('Hello do you fear anything or do you want a tricky question?');
```

Expected output would be an array containing the following to sentences:

```
['do you fear anything', 'a tricky question']
```

I am able to successfully do this for only the next line by exploding the sentence, then looping through each word like so

```
  if($currentLine == $currentWord){
    if($next_line == $next_word){
     // push to array
    }
  }
```

What I am struggling with is making the function go on until it doesn't find any more matches, aka a recursive function. Can you help?

Comment: did you get your solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $ip_array = array('a','y','c','d','g','i','x','a','c') ;
    $s_array  = array('y','c','g','i','x') ;
    $s_array_copy = $s_array ;
    $output_array = array() ;

    $count_s_array = count($s_array) ;
    $k = 0 ;

    for($i = 0 ; $i< $count_s_array ; $i = $i+$k){
        if( ( $pos = array_search($s_array[$i], $ip_array) ) >= 0 ){
            $output_str = $s_array[$i] ;
            for( $j = 1; $j < count($s_array_copy) ; $j++){
                if($s_array_copy[$j] == $ip_array[$pos+($j)]){

                    $output_str .= ' ' . $s_array_copy[$j] ;
                }else{  
                    break ;
                }                   
            }

            array_push($output_array, $output_str ) ;
            //echo '<br/>\n pushing array....<br/>********************<br>';
            for(;$k<$j;$k++){
                unset($s_array_copy[$k]);
            }
            $s_array_copy = array_values($s_array_copy);
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>' ;
        print_r($output_array) ;
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
array('y c', 'g i x');
```